# Error while assiging a value to a property

Tags: typescript

I have the below interface

```
let selectedQuantity = 4;
export interface CartItem {
  item: Item;
   quantity: number;

  }
let cartItem = <CartItem>{
  quantity: parseInt(this.selectedQuantity, 10),
  item: item
};
```

Any idea why I'm getting the below error while assigning value to quantity

```
Argument of type 'number' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.
```

Answer (score 1):

If you look at the signature for `parseInt`, you should see that it has a `string` as its first parameter and an optional `number` as its second parameter. You declare `selectedQuantity` with an initial assignment of `4`, which implicitly sets the type of `selectedQuantity` to `number`.

When you pass `selectedQuantity` into `parseInt` you are passing a `number` instead of a `string` as the first argument for `parseInt`. You should remove the call to `parseInt` or change the type of `selectedQuantity` to a `string` (e.g., `let selectedQuantity = "4"` instead of `let selectedQuantity = 4`, although I see no immediate reason to use a string here instead of a number).

Comment: thanks . You are right . the selectedQuantity variable was bound to an <select> component .. onchange the value it was setting the string value instead of number , which was breaking something else in the code.. have put the correct way of setting up select in angular for others                                                                                         
     `<select [(ngModel)]="selectedQuantity">
                <option *ngFor="let quant of quantities"
                        [ngValue]="quant"
                >
                  {{quant}}
                </option>`